# Call to the next most specific method does not work

Tags: methods, parameters, common-lisp, clos

Consider the class `account` :

```
(defclass account ()
  ((name :initarg :name :reader name)
   (balance :initarg :balance :initform 0.00 :accessor balance)
   (interest-rate :allocation :class :initform 0.06
                  :reader interest-rate)))
```

For this class, we define a method `withdraw` :

```
(defmethod withdraw ((acct account) amt)
  (if (< amt (balance acct))
      (decf (balance acct) amt)
      'insufficient-funds))
```

And, another class `password-account` , that is a subclass of `account`:

```
(defclass password-account (account)
  ((password :initarg :password :reader password )))
```

And, the method `withdraw`, for this class:

```
(defmethod withdraw ((acct password-account) amt pass)
  (if (equal (password acct) pass)
      (call-next-method acct amt )
      'wrong-password))
```

But this gives an error :

```
The generic function
#<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION COMMON-LISP-USER::WITHDRAW (1)>
takes 2 required arguments; was asked to find a method with
specializers
(#<STANDARD-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::PASSWORD-ACCOUNT>
 #1=#<SB-PCL:SYSTEM-CLASS COMMON-LISP:T> #1#)
   [Condition of type SB-PCL::FIND-METHOD-LENGTH-MISMATCH]
See also:
  Common Lisp Hyperspec, FIND-METHOD [:function]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "repl-thread" RUNNING {1005308033}>)
```

Why is this happening? And what does

> was asked to find a method with specializers

mean here?

Here, the primary `withdraw` function had two arguments `acct` and `amt`, so in order to call it from a more specific method, which uses 3 arguments instead of 2, we can provide `call-next-method` with the arguments of the less specific `withdraw` method. But this still isn't working.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can't have a method with two required parameters and another one with three required arguments in the same generic function. CLOS does not allow that. The first method definition determines the the number of required arguments. The generic function in your example has two required arguments and you try to define a method with three required arguments. This is not supported and also not allowed.

Comment: Thanks @RainerJoswig. Any particular reason for not supporting such methods?

Comment: And  what's the point of calling the next most specific method via `call-next-method` with arguments ? As all the methods would require the same number of arguments. (Thus the same arguments)

Comment: A generic function needs to have one valid number of required arguments.If that were not the case, a compiler would not be able to check that the correct number of required arguments have been provided.

Comment: No, not all methods require the same number of arguments. All what is required is that the methods have the same number of REQUIRED arguments. Methods can have additional arguments: optional arguments, keyword arguments, rest arguments.

Comment: @RainerJoswig So, making the argument `pass` optional should do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Congruent lambda lists for generic functions**

Methods of a generic function need to have [congruent](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_c.htm#congruent) *lambda lists*. The language standard describes what that means: [Congruent Lambda-lists for all Methods of a Generic Function](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/07_fd.htm).

As you can see the first rule says:

- Each lambda list must have the same number of required parameters.

*Required parameters* tell us which arguments **always** have to be provided. Generic functions additionally allow optional, keyword and rest arguments. But there is no dispatch over these. The dispatch only works over the required arguments and all of those.

Having the same number of required parameters makes dispatch easier and allows the compiler to check for function calls with the wrong number of arguments.

**Optional parameters need to be congruent, too**

Note also that all methods of a generic function need to have the same number of optional parameters. See the second rule in the standard.

**Wording**

- a *parameter* is something like a named variable in a lambda list
- an *argument* is provided in a call to a function

Examples:

```
(defun foo (a b) (list a b))
```

`a` and `b` are *parameters* for the function `foo`.

```
(foo (+ 2 3) (* 4 5))
```

`5` and `20` are the two *arguments* for the call of the function `foo`.